# jquery get width of div to left side window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, offset

And I want to get the width or distance or pixel that between the `div` and left side of of window/viewport.
And another width again between the `div` to the right side of the window.
I will use the width to create a left line and right line.
But I am poor in jQuery, I try `offset` but seems nothing happen.
So I back to 0 again so I didn't include fiddle here since I got nothing inside.
But I have attached with the image link as below, to explain my question.
Please help me on try to get the width, I can create the line myself.
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Please show us some code to see what have you tried.

Comment: Get the position from left and right of that div. :)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Put the code here in a **Snippet** or [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net).

Comment: I delete it already, since the jquery code is wrong, it affect my other functions. I stop at after I get the width of window. https://jsfiddle.net/rae0724/6w3xzxw9/1/

Comment: Still, my answer works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var of = $(ele).offset(), // this will return the left and top
    left = of.left, // this will return left 
    right = $(window).width() - left - $(ele).width() // you can get right by calculate
```

Maybe this can help you.
After all, `.width()` isn't the only answer, like `innerWidth()` or `outerWidth()`

Answer (score 0):

There is two options
One is you can use red line as image and you can place the div over the red line.
Second one,
If you want to calculate:

**Left div width = parent div width - child div offset;**

**Right div width = parent div width - child div offset + child div width;**

```
var parentdiv = document.getElementById("ParentDivID");
var parentWidth = parentdiv.offsetWidth;

var childdiv = document.getElementById("childDivID");
var childWidth = childdiv.offsetLeft;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easier to do with POJ (plain old javascript).  Get the position of the element on the screen.  Then evaluate its `left` property.  That will be the width of your left line.  Then subtract its `right` property from the width of the screen.  That will be the width of your right line.

```
var x = document.getElementById('myDiv').getBoundingClientRect();
var myLeftLineWidth = x.left;
var myRightLineWidth = screen.width - x.right;
```

For more information see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element).

If you want the width of the window instead of the screen, change `screen.width` to `window.innerWidth`.  If you don't want the scrollbar, etc. to be included in the width, use `document.documentElement.clientWidth`.  (For more info on these, see [this](http://ryanve.com/lab/dimensions/).)

Comment: Should'nt second line be `var myLeftLineWidth = x.left;` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with JavaScript, no need for jQuery:

```
var mydiv = document.getElementById('mydiv');
var offset = mydiv.getBoundingClientRect();

var offsetRight = document.documentElement.clientWidth - offset.right;
var offsetLeft = offset.left;
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ccr8mufq/2/)

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't hold up if you don't center the div horizontally; both the values returned are equal no matter what you set the left margin to be.  If you change `offsetRight` to = `document.documentElement.cientWidth - offset.right` it works out.

Comment: Seems like so. Thanks.

Comment: I'd probably do something like window.innerWidth - (offset.left + mydiv.clientWidth);

Answer (score 0):

We can work out that where the box starts with `.offset()`.
Next, we can work out where the box ends with `.offset() + .width()`.
We now know where our box sits on the x-axis.

Now let's see what we have to the left of our box with `.left` which can run on our `.offset()`.
We've now worked out how much space there is to the left and how wide our box is.

Finally, we can put what we've worked out together, we can get the page width `$(window).width()` and minus what there is to the left of our box (stage 2) and the width of our box (stage 1) and that will only leave what is to the right of our box.

That's the theory anyway now let's have a look at some code. You'll see I'm working out all the bits from the theory and then adding some visual representation.

```js
calcSizes = function() {
  var boxPos  = $(".box").offset(),
      toLeft  = boxPos.left,
      toRight = $(window).width() - ($(".box").width() + toLeft);

  $(".left").width(toLeft + "px");
  $(".right").width(toRight + "px");

  console.log("Right: " + toRight + "px");
  console.log("Left: "  + toLeft + "px");
  console.log("Width: " + $(".box").width() + "px");
  console.log(
    $(window).width() + "px = " +
    toRight           + "px + " +
    toLeft            + "px + " +
    $(".box").width() + "px"
  );
  console.log(" ");
}

calcSizes();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
.box,
.indicator {
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center
}
.box {
  width: 100px;
  background: #FF5722;
  margin-left: 60%
}
.indicator {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient( 45deg, #F44336, #F44336 10px, #D32F2F 10px, #D32F2F 20px);
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translatey(-100%);
  opacity: .8
}
.left {
  float: left
}
.right {
  float: right
}
button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 55px;
  left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">BOX</div>
<div class="left indicator">
  LEFT
</div>
<div class="right indicator">
  RIGHT
</div>

<button onclick="calcSizes()">
  Recalculate
</button>
```

Hope this makes sense and helps you with your project.